# Change default API spec URL in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using the Swagger Editor Docker image for defining my API specification and generate a nodejs server to run as stub api and serve the documentation for my API spec.

I would like to know if it is possible to change the default URL to my own in order to present my spec when I open the page, and how I would do that.

[image]

For instance, I would like to change the default address to `http://localhost:8080/spec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you used Swagger Codegen to generate a Node.js server. Now when you `npm start` and open Swagger UI, you want the input box (the spec URL) to display http://localhost:8080/**spec** instead of http://localhost/**api-docs**.

To change the path the .yaml spec is served from, edit your `index.js` as follows:

```js
// 1 - add swaggerUi options
var uiOptions = {
  apiDocs: '/spec'  // <-- override the default /api-docs
};

swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {
  ...

  // 2 - pass these options to swaggerUi
  app.use(middleware.swaggerUi(uiOptions));
```

The port number is specified by the `serverPort` variable in `index.js`:

```js
var serverPort = 8080;
```