# Change default port for swagger-ui dist bundle

Tags: swagger-ui

How would you go about changing the default port of swagger-ui **dist** version?

By default it listens to requests on port `8080`. I want it to listen to some other port. The use case is that we want to have a couple of dists running on our host but listening on different ports.

Is this possible or do you actually need to do some more complicated setup?

We run it via node js default package:

```
{
  "name": "dist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "swagger-ui-bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: How do you run Swagger UI?

Comment: Via node.js default http server.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45176511/113116) help?

Comment: Not quite..it should be in dist folder.  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist

Comment: Swagger UI is a static web page, what port it's served from depends on the server you use and server config. Just to clarify, do you mean the [swagger-ui-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-dist) npm package?

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24750341/113116)?

Comment: @Helen, yes something like that but if I do that in my package.json will swagger-ui-dist actually change the default port from 8080 to the one I define? Hmm. I will test this and get back to you. If it works you can add this as an answer.

Comment: @Helen, yes that worked! I had to write like this   `"scripts": {
    "start": "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000"
  },`

Comment: You can include it as an answer so I can check it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The simples solution that I know Is just to use docker and map port by `-p 80:8080`:

https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-ui/

`docker run -p 80:8080 -e API_URL=http://generator.swagger.io/api/swagger.json swaggerapi/swagger-ui`

In case if you not use API_URL  [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/Dockerfile) is docker file for above docker - you cna use this information `SWAGGER_JSON "/app/swagger.json"` to map path to swagger.json in your local machine (using docker `--volume` parameter)

Comment: That would be my choice but in our environment on the preferred server we cannot use docker. Otherwise we would have gone with this approach.